# Failed to create virtual server: A virtual server with the same name and port already exists - but this is not visible

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, ubuntu-16.04, webmin

(I have spent much time Googling and searching the Internet - including this forum - to no avail.

After trying to create a new vhost in webadmin I get back following:

> Failed to create virtual server: A virtual server with the same name
>   and port already exists - but this is not visible!

How do I overcome this issue?

**Relevant Information**

I cannot see the above-mentioned newly created virtual server.

To get this far I have followed  https://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Apache_Webserver

**Update**

I found another great resource at 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04  -  I'll work through it and come back with any updates.

[b]How To Set Up Apache Virtual Hosts  [/b]

Step One — Create the Directory Structure

Step Two — Grant Permissions

Step Three — Create Demo Pages for Each Virtual Host

Step Four — Create New Virtual Host Files

Step Five — Enable the New Virtual Host Files
Now that we have created our virtual host files, we must enable them. Apache includes some tools that allow us to do this.
We can use the a2ensite tool to enable each of our sites like this:

Step Six — Set Up Local Hosts File (Optional)

Step Seven — Test your Results
Now that you have your virtual hosts configured, you can test your setup easily by going to the domains that you configured in your web browser:

Well - i will go like the guy explains and suggests.

Comment: This may not be an appropriate forum due to the nature of the information needed to solve your problem. Never the less, you may want to advise what webserver you are using (Apache 2.4?) and what you mean by "its not visible" - ie.are.ypu referring to the site or config for the virtualhost.

Comment: Do you know how to use SSH, and are yiu in a posituon to provide the configs?  Alsi, what OS/distro?

Comment: I have heavily edited this post to make it more readable and in line with our standards (problem focussed rather then ego stroking).  Please check that I have not left out anything important or changed the nature of the question.   Also, you may want to consider **NOT** reproducing the summary of steps in the text - unless you intend to fill in findings related to them?  Also, double check the tabs - I've assumed you are using Ubuntu 16.04 and apache based on your update, but you don't actually state this !

Comment: If you can follow that tutorial, you presumably can use SSH.  Try running "sudo apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS | less" and look at the output to see if it mentions the host you can't find - if so, it means its configured, and it should tell you what file and line its configured at.